# APPLICATION FAILED TO START due to same bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I have a **Spring Webflux** application where I am trying to load a dependency from an old module (old module is on **Spring WebMVC** framework).

When the application is launched, this error is thrown -

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/web/reactive/config/DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

I want all the beans from webflux package to be initiated, so I can't set `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`.

Also tried excluding all classes within org.springframework.boot at the time of component scan - `@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "org.springframework.boot*")`. 
Also tried excluding all spring packages in pom.xml of my webflux project like this -

```
 <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

Since I cannot modify the older dependency project to webflux, are there any options I could use the make the code work ?

Answer (score 9):

In your Spring Boot startup class, the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation will auto configure the MVC part (`WebMvcAutoConfiguration` will fail due to same bean name in `DelegatingWebFluxConfiguration`)

So try to exclude this from auto config like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
}
```

Comment: try to replace `@SpringBootApplication` by `@Configuration @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class }) @ComponentScan`

Comment: In addtion to the mentioned fix, if you have annotated your controller with `@EnableWebMvc` annotation then the error may not go away. You will have to get rid of this annotation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue with reactive web you can mention it for Spring like this. then spring will manage it.

```
spring.main.web-application-type=reactive
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your problem description, Using dependencies of Spring MVC in Spring Webflux can cause this issue. I have solved this issue by excluding the group "org.springframework.boot" while including the old dependency.

In gradle.build i have did something like below:

```
implementation("dependency-using-spring-mvc") {
    exclude(group= "org.springframework.boot")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly you have some Web-related dependencies on the classpath but aren't building a web application, you can explicitly tell `SpringApplication` that you don't want a web application:

```
app.setWebEnvironment(false);
```

This is the way to disabling Web-related auto-configuration as it means you don't need to know what those auto-configuration classes are and lets Spring Boot take care of it for you.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it's a web application.